# javascript .onclick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to trigger a function when user clicks on `<img class="gallery_image">` but it doesn't work.

The script is at the very bottom of the body:

```
<script>

    document.getElementsByClassName('gallery_image').onclick = function (event) {
        console.log('click')
        event = event || window.event;
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
            link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
            options = {index: link, event: event},
            links = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('a');
        blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
    };

</script>
```

And there are `<img>` elements inside a table.

```
<img class="gallery_image" src="...IMG_20170907_192537_A1rqcbg.jpg.230x200_q85_crop.jpg" alt="">
```

Click on such image do nothing (nothing is logged into the console). Do you know why?

Comment: I supposed that DOM is ready. No, all such elements are there in first response.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('gallery_image')` returns an array, you need to iterate and add listeners to each item.

Comment: @zero298 it returns an HTMLCollection not an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation says [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array.

Use of :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('gallery_image')[0].onclick
```

or with `forEach` if they are multiple elements.

Because the returns of the method is `Array-like` but not an instance of `Array`, here is how you loop on it :

```js
const matches = document.getElementsByClassName('example');

Array.from(matches).forEach((x) => {
  x.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```

```css
.example {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
</div>

<div class="example">
</div>

<div class="example">
</div>
```

---

Example from the documentation :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parent-id">
        <p>hello word1</p>
        <p class="test">hello word2</p>
        <p >hello word3</p>
        <p>hello word4</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        var parentDOM = document.getElementById("parent-id");

        var test=parentDOM.getElementsByClassName("test");//test is not target element
        console.log(test);//HTMLCollection[1]

        var testTarget=parentDOM.getElementsByClassName("test")[0];//here , this element is target
        console.log(testTarget);//<p class="test">hello word2</p>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It returns an array-like HTMLCollection

Comment: @Luca is absolutely right and the distinction between the two is important.

Comment: What is `Array.like`?

Comment: @Luca I write too much of js :D typo

Answer (score 0):

it is because getElementsByClassName always returns an array
so to access that array objects , you must use syntax like

```
document.getElementsByClassName('gallery_image')[0].onclick = function(){
//your function goes here
}
```

here 0 is the array element returned by `document.getElementsByClassName('gallery_image')`

always execute this type of function after dom is ready

Answer (score 0):

Please use [`EventTarget#addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in composition with [`Element#querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.gallery_image').forEach(element => element.addEventListener(galleryImageClick));

function galleryImageClick(event) {
  console.log(click);
  // do the rest
}
```

If you want to pick one particular element, use `document.querySelector` as it returns a reference to a Node instead of NodeList:

```
document.querySelector('.gallery_image').addEventListener(galleryImageClick);
```

As mentioned in comments, you need to make sure the DOM is ready by the moment you establish the event listener. You need to add an appropriate event listener for that:

```
// vanilla JS way
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // query the DOM, add event listeners, etc.
});

// or jQuery way
$(document).ready(() => {
  // query the DOM, add event listeners, etc.
});
```

Hope it helps.

On a side note, please check out why [assigning value to "onclick" property of an element is a bad practice](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/3kamqn/why_is_inline_onclickfunction_considered_such_a/). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier and more efficient way to handling a click event for multiple nodes called **[Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)**:

- Find a parent element of the group of elements that need to listen for a click event.
- Register the click event to that parent element. Now whenever a child element is clicked, the parent element hears the event and then invokes the callback function. #ids, .classes, [names] are not necessary to find the clicked node because being registered to an event allows it to utilize the Event Object property [**`event.target`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

I noticed that you may not know about the return of methods such as [**`getElementsByClassName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName),[**`getElementsByName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)[**`getElementsByTagName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) or [**`querySelectorAll`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) or **[`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)**, etc.These properties and methods return an *array-like* object called a [**HTMLCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) or [**NodeList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). To properly handle this type of data structure requires that each item be looped through array method or a for loop.

---

The first function listens for the click event on an image them zooms it in or zooms it out. The second part gathers all of the images into a NodeList then assigns an index number to it's url.

#### Demo

```js
// Reference the parent node
var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');

// Register the parent to the click event
gallery.onclick = zoomImg;

// Callbak function
function zoomImg(e) {

  // if the clicked element is an IMG tag
  if (e.target.tagName === "IMG") {

    // Add/Remove the .zoom class 
    e.target.classList.toggle('zoom');
  }
  return false;
}

// Collect all .image classes into a NodeList
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.image');

/* Loop the NodeList through the forEach() method
|| On each loop add an index number to each of the images' src
*/
images.forEach(function(img, idx) {
  img.src = `http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=${idx+1}`;
});
```

```css
.image {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.zoom {
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<section id='gallery'>
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
  <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/50?text=">
</section>
```